# Is it possible to mix gradients with solid colors?

Tags: css, gradient, background-color

I was reading about [gradients](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp) and was wondering whether it is possible, **for one given `div`**, to mix solid and gradient colors as the CSS of its `background`.

I was thinking about this in the context of a bar which would represent the alternance of day and night: `white` for the day (50% of the `div` width), then a gradient from `white` to `black` (= dusk, 20% of the `div`width) and then `black` (30% of the `div` width). The percentages are just to set the context, the actual lengths would be calculated.

The documentation for gradients seems to imply that the mix is not possible, i.e. the possibility to set several stops is available, but each of them is faded into (so no solid colors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following solution using the [`linear-gradient`](https://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/):

```css
body {
  background:grey;
}
div {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, 
    white 0%, white 50%, 
    white 50%, black 70%, 
    black 70%, black 100%);
  height:200px;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes you can but there is a bit of calculation needed if you want to split multiple sections:

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 50%,rgba(127,127,127,1) 70%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /*
```

If you want to split the second section 20/30, then you need to know the calculate the middle RGB value between black and white, which is easy enough. Other colours would be more difficult